# how to access nested json objects with access information specified elsewhere without using eval or iteration?

Tags: javascript, json, navigation

i have a JSON object something like;

```
 var data = {
 Name : "test name",
 Type : "test type",
 VendorInfo :{
               FirstName : "Vendor First Name",
               LastName : "Vendor Last Name",
               Address : "Vendor Address",
               City : "Vendor City",
               ZipCode : "Zip"
             }
 }
```

now separately i want to keep info on how to access the fields in the data var

```
var accessInfo=[
    { fieldName : "Name", actionName : "Edit" },
    { fieldName : "Type", actionName : "Edit" },
    :
    :etc..
 ]
```

now in my javascript i can iterate over the accessInfo array by a for loop, something like;

`for(var i=0;i<accessInfo.length;i++){

      data[accessInfo[i].fieldName] = "changed field";

   }`

that works fine for top level fields, but i cannot figure out how to access the fields lower down in the hierarchy.. like data.VendorInfo.FirstName, data.VendorInfo.LastName etc.

Is this at all possible? i tried putting "VendorInfo.FirstName" and [VendorInfo][FirstName], but no go..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to parse your access specification to traverse the target object.  You can use a function like this:

```
function getProp(obj, propName) {
   var prop;
   var props = propName.split('.');
   for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
      prop = obj[props[i]];
      if (typeof prop === 'null' || typeof prop === 'undefined') return prop;
   }
  return prop;
}
```

Comment: i think getProp() in your answer will return the value of the prop, i need to be able to change it, that is why i m trying to access it directly..

Comment: you can do a method assignProp(obj, propName, value) similarly, only assign before you reach the leaf node of the object, so that you are doing it by reference:

obj[props[i]] = newValue

Comment: yes i think i can. I guess there is no way to do it directly as i was trying? Marking as answered, thanks for your help Elijah